# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL when doPost is overriden

Tags: forms, post, jetty, http-status-code-405

I am aware there are many posts with the same name, but I still can not find the issue. I am trying to submit a registration form using post to register a user in a database, but I am getting the title error when I click the submit button. This seems to be caused by not having a

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
```

in the class being called, but I do have one which is why I can't see the problem.

The form being submitted is at the URL: /Story/register

```
<form method="post" action="RegisterHandler">
    <label>Username: <input type="text" name="desired_username" value="" size="10"></label><br><br>
    <label>Password: <input type="password" name="desired_pass" value="" size="10"></label><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Register">
</form>
```

On submit the url becomes /Story/RegisterHandler. I have a dispatcher that maps this url to the actual Registerhandler class.

```
 URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
 String path = url.getPath();
 String parts[] = path.split("/");
 if(parts.length>2){
                        if("story".equals(parts[2])){
                                this.log(requestIp + ": " + "- User: Sean - Email: test@test.com - Accessed a story.");
                                new Story().doGet(request, response);
                        } else if ("about".equals(parts[2])){
                                log(requestIp + ": " + "- User: Sean - Email: test@test.com - Accessed a the about page");
                                about(request, out, cfg);
                        } else if ("default.css".equals(parts[2])){ //needed because dispatcher sends href to external stylesheet to the default page
                                defaultCss(request, out, cfg);
                        } else if ("register".equals(parts[2])){
                                log(requestIp + ": " + "- User: Sean - Email: test@test.com - Accessed a the register page.");
                                register(request, out, cfg);
                        } else if ("RegisterHandler".equals(parts[2])){
                                log(requestIp + ": " + "- User: Sean - Email: test@test.com - Accessed RegisterHandler");
                                new RegisterHandler().doPost(request, response);
                        } else {
                                log(requestIp + ": " + "- User: Sean - Email: test@test.com - Accessed the default page");
                                new Default().doGet(request, response);
                        }
```

The dispatcher works in all cases, besides the RegisterHandler case which I assume is because of the error.

The RegisterHandler class is as follows:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_22);
            cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/home/ubuntu/jetty-distribution-9.3.3.v20150827/cse383base/webapps/Story"));
            cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            try {
                    this.generatePage(request, out, cfg);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(out);
            }
    }
```

I know that the if statement in the Dispatcher is getting the right URL from the submit button because any other URL would just go to the default page.

Does anyone see why it is saying the url doesn't support POST?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is the message ...

```
HTTP method POST is not supported
```

That message is produced by the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` `doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` default implementation.

See: https://github.com/jetty-project/codehaus-servlet-api/blob/servlet-3.0/src/main/java/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java#L351-L361

This means the Request URI that was issued is hitting a Servlet that does not have `void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` overridden.

What to investigate:

- What is your Request URI as seen on the server side? (most important part will be the URI.path)
- What is the actual Servlet being hit by your client?
- What does that Servlet have declared for its `doPost()` call?